# CustomCell without customCell class

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, storyboard

this is my problem. I would to create a custom cell without create a custom cell class. 
I know that this is possible. I've created in storyboard a tableviewcontroller with a prototype cell with a label. In the attibutes I've set the cell name "mycell". And the code that I used is:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"mycell";
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   if (cell == nil) 
   { cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];}
   UILabel *title = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:1];
   title.text = @"Hi";
   return cell;
}
```

But when my app run I see only a empty table without a cell with my label.

Comment: Are you returning something in the numberOfRows method?

Comment: Try: cell.title.text = @"Hi"; U sure that how many row u want to show.

Comment: Could u show the code of UITableViewDataSource ?

Comment: I've used simple numbers in the tableView methods - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{ return 1;}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{ return 5; }

Answer (score 0):

Your UILabel title is nil. First create a UILabel and add as a subview to your cell. You can do this like below

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {  
     static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"mycell";
     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
     if (cell == nil) {
         cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
     }

     UILabel *title = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:1];
     if (title == nil) {
         title = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 15)];
         title.tag = 1;
         [cell.contentView addSubview:title];
     }

     title.text = @"Hi";
     return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thank you but if I use this code I alloc a Label in the code and there is not corrispondence between the label allocate, with label in storyboard with tag 1.

Comment: you used tag 1 in your question. you can change it to fit your needs.